# Match dates using two date columns as range

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to create a column within databricks using pyspark.  I need to check if date column is found between two other date columns and if it is then 1 if it is not then 0.  I am wanting to call this ground truth, since this will tell me if on date it's found in between the two date columns. This is what I have so far:

df = (df
.withColumn("Ground_truth_IE", when(col("ReadingDateTime").between(col("EventStartDateTime") & col("EventEndDateTime")), 1).otherwiste(0)
)
)

But I continue to get an error:

TypeError: between() missing 1 required positional argument: 'upperBound'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `between()` operator in pyspark should be used like: `between(lowerBound, upperBound)`

```
df = df.withColumn("Ground_truth_IE", when(col("ReadingDateTime")\
        .between(col("EventStartDateTime"),col("EventEndDateTime")), 1).otherwise(0))
```

Comment: Thank you, Cena!  This solution worked.  I was also able to see where my error was.  Thanks again!